# Cannot access variable outside function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

Have been reading around, and now very confused. I'm trying to access a local variable in the global scope. I have removed the var inside the function, but it is still coming back as "undefined". I'm sure I'm just missing something - any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
var totalcostApple;

function shopping() {

    $("#apple").on("keyup", function () {

    var quantity = $("#apple").val();

    totalcostApple = (quantity * 0.2).toFixed(2);


     });

};

shopping();

console.log(totalcostApple);
```

Comment: you are trying to log the variable before it has been evaluated in the keyup event. Please explain expectations in more detail

Comment: What I'd like to do is be able to access the totalcostApple variable outside the shopping function after the keyup event. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. But in your case you are accessing the variable *before* the event happened. If you run `console.log(totalcostApple);` *after* the event it will work as expected.

Comment: I thought I was - I'm doing it after I call the function (I thought...)

Comment: @user3858292 no, `totalcostApple` will remain undefined until the event actually occurs and runs the handler code

Comment: Your `shopping` function does nothing, except bind `keyup` event to the `#apple` element. You assign value to `totalcostApple` when you input something into the `#apple`. Without doing that, `totalcostApple` will always be `undefined`.

Comment: Okay - but even when I've input something, it does say "totalcostApple is undefined". I'll just keep playing around.

Comment: This is a classic bad pattern in asynchronous programming.  To get a good result, the program needs to wait until totalcostApple is changed before accessing it, but instead does so immediately.  Every day people ask this question, usually in ajax applications.  But you don't need ajax to have it.  Any kind of event handling brings it out.

Comment: similar to common ajax woes in:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: Hi guys - thanks for all your help! I've managed to figure it out, by asking users to hit a submit button. This has worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding what you are doing. The flow of your code is all messed up. When you call `shopping()` you instruct the browser to tie the keyup event to the apple object. Right after tying it to the object however, you query the variable. But you are simply not fast enough to generate a keyup event between the `shopping` function and the `keyup` event. Just to show you, instead of logging to the console just that once, try logging it to the console at another time. At any time. Add the following line of code:

`$(window).on('click', function(){ console.log(totalcostApple); });`

Now you can test *when* your variable has actually changed. Every time you click, it will log the current value of the `totalcostApple` to the console.

But actually, you should improve your code as such:

```
// add some code to assure that everything you do only gets executed after the DOM is ready
$(document).ready(function(){
    // add a default value to your totalcost.
    var totalcostApple = 0;

    function shopping() {
        // remove your keyup event from here and tie it in directly.
        var quantity = $("#apple").val();
        totalcostApple = (quantity * 0.2).toFixed(2);
        // move your log inside the event so you can see it when it *changes*
        console.log(totalcostApple);
    };

    $("#apple").on("keyup", shopping);
});
```